# <meta> tag to turn off cache is not working

Tags: caching

I've a html page which is picking random .txt file as an input and dipslay a graph using AmcCharts(js framework). After every 10 min, old .txt file is removed and new is created automatically. My HTML is picking old .txt from cache and not the new .txt generated.

I've tried

```
<meta http-equiv='cache-control' content='no-cache'>
<meta http-equiv='expires' content='0'>
<meta http-equiv='pragma' content='no-cache'>
```

but they're not working.

Comment: Duplicate - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1341089/using-meta-tags-to-turn-off-caching-in-all-browsers

Comment: @dwhite.me: Not a duplicate, as this is about files that are cached, not the page itself.

Comment: thanks dwhite...Can anyone please tell how to modify my html page so that on refresh it picks the newly created file and not the older one in the cache..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The meta tags only determine how the page itself is cached, not how any files that you load from the page is cached.

If you can use server scripting to handle the requests for the text file, you could add the cache settings to the response as HTTP headers, to set the cacheability of the request.

Otherwise you would need to make the URL that you use to request the file unique each time by adding a parameter to it. You can for example use Javascript to generate a random number and add as a parameter, so that you request for exampe `data.txt?8973624895723405` instead of just `data.txt`.